# jQuery traversal

Tags: jquery

I have a table with a couple of rows:

```
   <tr class='data'>
        <td class='img'><img class='thumbnail' src='ProductImages/img_1894_72.jpg'/></td>
        <td class='bc_img'><img class='thumbnail' src='ProductImages/img_1893_72.jpg'/></td>
   </tr>

    <tr class='data'>
        <td class='img'><img class='thumbnail' src='ProductImages/img_1318_72.jpg'/></td>
        <td class='bc_img'><img class='thumbnail' src='ProductImages/img_1646_72.jpg'/></td>
    </tr>
```

The images in the cells are thumbnail images (the 72 in the name specifies a 72px width). I want to write some jQuery that will let me click the second td in either row, sense which of the two rows I chose, and replace the src image in that row with a larger version of the same image, i.e., replace the 72 in the src name with a 300.

My problem is getting from the clicked td to the raw img node within that td. I've been playing with:

```
$("td.bc_img").click(function () {
    console.log("1. this is " , this);  
    imgNode = $(this).find('img').get();
    console.log("2. imgNode is " , imgNode);
    console.log("3. imgNode.src is " , imgNode.src);
    var thumbSrc = ?;  // not sure how to get this
    var bigImgSrc = thumbSrc.replace(/_72\.jpg/, "_900.jpg");
});
```

And that produces the console output:

[image: Console output]

But that doesn't seem to be what I need.  I think I need to get something that looks like:

```
              <img class="thumbnail" src="ProductImages/img_1893_72.jpg">
```

before I can add .src to it and modify the src.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is returning an array of elements (notice the square brackets around the prettified console text), which has no `src` property. Get the first element of that array (or use `.get(0)`, which does the same thing):

```
> $('img').get();
[img]
> $('img').get()[0];
<img src="foo.jpg" />
> $('img').get(0);
<img src="foo.jpg" />
```

You can also get the `src` attribute out of the jQuery object using `.attr('src')`

Answer (score 2):

The key is that you use `$(this).find("img")` to find the image in the cell that received the click.

```
$("td.bc_img").click(function () {
    var img = $(this).find("img").get(0);
    img.src = img.src.replace(/_72\.jpg/, "_900.jpg");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `get(0)` to get the DOM object for the image:

```
imgNode = $(this).find('img').get(0);
```

Now I believe the value of `thumbSrc` can be set to `imgNode.src`.

http://jsfiddle.net/xyH6v/

Answer (score 1):

I changed some lines of code to get the required src and change the attribute

```
$("td.bc_img").click(function () {
        console.log('rw');
        imgNode = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
        console.log("The image node source is " , imgNode);
        $(this).find('img').attr('src', 'put your replacement url here');
});
```

The fiddle URL is http://jsfiddle.net/8fd8Q/1/

Comment: What is this `$(this + ' > img')`.  I can't imagine that that works.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry was just accessing the immediate child of $(this)....changed the code to reflect that. please let me know if that doesn't apply here

Comment: You can't do `$(imgNode + ' > img')` either.  Selectors are strings and don't have jQuery objects or DOM nodes in them.  This will not work.